# Are Spring Boot starter dependencies production-ready?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-starter

I'm learning spring boot to develop an eCommerce website by myself. I consider that starter dependencies like `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-security` can be used for a production environment or just for learning purposes?

Comment: What makes you think it's only for learning?

Spring Boot is a production ready application framework.

And what vulnerabilities?

Comment: Because the name `starter`

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. I've provided an answer to your question about Spring Boot. Please post your question about JPA separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "starters" are Spring Boot's dependency management and auto-configuration mechanism. The term "starter" does not aim to indicate that it's for non-production uses cases, it is probably just used to emphasize that it gets you started quickly. See the following explanation from [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.build-systems.starters):

> Starters are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application. You get a one-stop shop for all the Spring and related technologies that you need without having to hunt through sample code and copy-paste loads of dependency descriptors.

In order to understand starter dependencies better, I suggest reviewing [section "Creating Your Own Starter" from the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.custom-starter).